JavaFX (Cannot invoke "javafx.stage.Stage.setScene(javafx.scene.Scene)" because "this.stage" is null) Solution?
I am trying to have buttons switch the scene on the stage. The starting scene is the login screen, and I have no issue transitioning from there to the dashboard scene. The issue is when I call clickAccount method.
I checked that fxid is correct and all fxml files will load properly if I initialize them as the first scene.
package ui;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import logic.UserDriver;

import java.io.IOException;


public class BudgetApplication extends Application {
    public UserDriver userDriver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // Initialize UserDriver
        userDriver = new UserDriver();

        // Load FXML and get controller
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();

        // Load dashboard FXML
        FXMLLoader dashboardLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("dashboard.fxml"));
        Parent dashboardRoot = dashboardLoader.load();

        // Initialize dashboardScene
        Scene dashboardScene = new Scene(dashboardRoot, 1280, 720);

        //Load account FXML
        FXMLLoader accountLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("accounts.fxml"));
        Parent accountRoot = accountLoader.load();

        //Initialize accountScene
        Scene accountScene = new Scene(accountRoot, 1280, 720);

        // Get the controller instance and set up dependencies
        BudgetController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setUserDriver(userDriver);  // Pass userDriver to the controller
        controller.setStage(primaryStage);     // Pass the stage to the controller if needed
        controller.setDashboardScene(dashboardScene); // Pass dashboardScene to controller
        controller.setAccountScene(accountScene); //Pass accountScene to controller

        // Set the primary scene
        Scene loginScene = new Scene(root, 500, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(loginScene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaBucks");
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> controller.windowClose("UserInfo.ser"));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


}


package ui;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import logic.UserDriver;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BudgetController {

    @FXML public TextField usernameTF;
    @FXML public TextField passwordTF;
    @FXML public Button loginButton;
    @FXML public Button accountButton;

    private UserDriver userDriver;
    private Stage stage;
    private Scene dashboardScene;
    private Scene accountScene;
    private Parent root;
    // Setters to pass data from BudgetApplication
    public void setUserDriver(UserDriver userDriver) {
        this.userDriver = userDriver;
    }

    public void setStage(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
        System.out.println("Stage set in controller: " + (stage != null));
    }

    public void setDashboardScene(Scene dashboardScene){
        this.dashboardScene = dashboardScene;
    }
    public void setAccountScene(Scene accountScene){
        this.accountScene = accountScene;
    }

    @FXML
    public void clickLogin(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        String username = usernameTF.getText();
        String password = passwordTF.getText();

        // Debug output
        System.out.println("Username: " + username);
        System.out.println("Password: " + password);

        // Validate login
        if (userDriver != null && userDriver.validateLogin(username, password)) {
            System.out.println("Login successful!");
            usernameTF.clear();
            passwordTF.clear();
            stage.setScene(dashboardScene);

        } else {
            System.out.println("Login failed.");
            usernameTF.clear();
            passwordTF.clear();
        }
    }
    @FXML
    public void clickAccount() {
        System.out.println("Button binded");
        stage.setScene(accountScene);
    }

    public void windowClose(String filename) {
        userDriver.writeToFile(filename);
        System.out.println("Data saved to " + filename);
    }
}




Don't you need to pass the stage to all the controllers, not just the one that is created when you load login.fxml?

You probably need to create and post a complete [mre] (one where we can copy and paste the code, with no additions, and run it to see the error) to get a definitive answer here. Create some minimal FXML files (probably all you need is a button in one and a label in the other(s)), omit (or at worst, mock) the login validation, and remove anything that is not needed to demonstrate the problem.

If you are using the same class for controllers for different FXML files, don't. Each FXML should have its own controller class.

For another approach to switching views in a JavaFX application, study this example

Get the stage like that in any controller and don't use the setter:
Stage Stage = (Stage) anyNodeInYourControllerWothFxmlBinding.getScene().getWindow();

This will make sure that the stage is not null. That snippet will only fail if the used node has no binding to the fxml file.
